# Cassandra console log messages

Tags: java, logging, cassandra

I'm using DataStax Cassandra on Windows 10 and accessing in Java. The log messages are appended to Eclipse console. I need to out them to the logger. I tried to update the logbakc and logback-tools xml files but got no effect.
I changed the level of STDOUT appender in logback to ERROR to print only the errors, the restarted the service but got no effect, all the messages are kept displayed in the console

```
appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-5level %date{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

Any advise?

Comment: what do you mean by "I need to out them to logger" ? do you want then to output to a log file ?

Comment: Right. But also I need to set the level to Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using consoleAppender(which appends on the console) use a file appender like this

> ```
> < configuration >
>
> <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
>
> <file>testFile.log< /file>
>
> <append>true< /append>
>
> </appender>   
> <root level="ERROR">
>   <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
>  </root>
> </configuration>`
> ```

You can read more  about different appenders here : http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html